# Infinite loop when looping through 3 elements. Whats wrong?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create some "plugin" like the facebook like button. 
However my loop renders only the first div. and not other divs. why?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9WjA/3/)

```
    <style>body{background: #ccc;}</style>

<div name="q" data-id="3"  data-width="200"></div>
<div name="q" data-id="1"  data-width="300"></div>
<div name="q" data-id="1"  data-width="400"></div>

<script>

    var s = document.getElementsByName("q");

    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        e = s[i];

        w = e.attributes['data-width'].value; 
        i = e.attributes['data-id'].value;

        var o={};

        o.iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        o.iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://resources2.news.com.au/images/2012/09/27/1226482/758034-tardar-sauce-the-cat.jpg');
        o.iframe.width = w;
        o.iframe.height = w + 100;
        o.iframe.border = 0;
        o.iframe.setAttribute('style', 'border: 0;overflow: visible;');

        e.appendChild(o.iframe);

        console.log('id:'+i+' width:'+w);
    }   

</script>
```

Comment: You are assigning `i` again in the loop.

Comment: Right. Fixed it but it still cant render the other two divs.

Comment: `i = e.attributes['data-id'].value;` ? really?

Comment: @RakeshJuyal Please don't sound too patronising

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V9WjA/4/ They are appearing, but they were appearing very far below the first `iframe` (like, 1000's of pixels) so i added `display: inline-block;` and added class `.iframeclass` to each `iframe` with a `width`.

Comment: Thanks MackieeE :) Works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the variable `i` both as a loop counter, and inside the loop.

In the first iteration you assign the value `"3"` to the variable `i`. That will be converted to the number `3` when compared in the `for` statement, and as that is more than the length of the array, the loop ends after the first iteration.

Use a different variable name for the variable that holds the data-id in the loop.

---

#### Edit:

The problem with the size of the iframes is here:

```
o.iframe.height = w + 100;
```

The variable `w` contains a string, for example `"200"`, and when any of the operands of the `+` operator is a string, it will do string concatenation. So the result is not `300` but `"200100"`. Your iframes are several thousand pixels high.

You need to use numbers in the calculation:

```
o.iframe.height = parseInt(w) + 100;
```

Comment: Thank. My bad for that error. I have changed the var name but it still cant render the divs correctly. Any clue?

Comment: @Muffin, why did you accept the answer if your problem is not yet solved?

Answer (score 1):

`i` is being modified within your loop. Change the name of this declaration inside your loop:

```
newNameForVar = e.attributes['data-id'].value;
```